What's the minimum spec USB-C cable for extended desktop to an iPad from a Macbook?
iPads support extended desktop over WiFi and USB. To use over USB which is the cheapest cable data type?
Usb-C with USB 2.0, 10Gbps, thunderbolt or other label.
There quite a price difference in supported speeds, so I want the cheapest that would work.

I use the Belkin 4k USB-C monitor cable and it works fine

@Le_Petit_Prince That's a $30 cable, I've reworded my question.

Splurge on the best cable you can afford. You may need to use it for higher-speed connections later.

There are several generations of iPad and MacBook that support this. Are you looking for a specific Mac and specific iPad on specific OS versions or so thing that’s guaranteed to work with the highest spec and cost possible combination?

Its a USB Type-C 3.1, DisplayPort as stated on gsmarena.com
